# A big 'like' matching query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got 2 tables, 
'[Item] with field [name] nvarchar(255)
'[Transaction] with field [short_description] nvarchar(3999)

And I need to do thus :

```
Select [Transaction].id,  [Item].id 
From [Transaction] inner join [Item]
on [Transaction].[short_description] like ('%' + [Item].[name] + '%')
```

The above works if limited to a handful of items, but unfiltered is just going over 20 mins and I cancel.

I have a NC index on [name], but I cannot index [short_description] due to its length.

```
[Transaction] has 320,000 rows
[Items] has 42,000.
```

That's 13,860,000,000 combinations.

Is there a better way to perform this query ?
I did poke at full-text, but I'm not really that familiar, the answer was not jumping out at me there.

Any advice appreciated !!

Comment: You are joining on a wildcard. There is no way to make that faster. It has to compare every single item against every single transaction.

Comment: This could be a case where denormalization makes sense. You could create a separate table to cross-reference item names and transaction short descriptions. Triggers on both tables would keep the cross reference up-to-date. If you could tolerate some stale data you could forego triggers and schedule a job to refresh the cross-reference at suitable times.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a comparison string with a wildcard (% or _) will NEVER use an index, and will typically be disastrous for performance. Your query will need to scan indexes rather than seek through them, so indexing won't help.

Ideally, you should have a third table that would allow a many-to-many relationship between Transaction and Item based on IDs. The design is the issue here.

Comment: There can be some benefit even from an index scan. An index scan will typically require less I/O than a table scan. The smaller the index width relative to the row width the greater the benefit.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more precise, but unless you're looking at filtered indexes, you're probably looking at either a table scan, or a clustered index scan, so just as big. The root of the problem the OP brought up is still the design. Joining on some middle portion of text isn't scalable.

Answer (score 0):

After some more sleuthing I have utilized some Fulltext features.

**sp_fulltext_keymappings**
gives me my transaction table id, along with the FT docID
*(I found out that 'doc' = text field)*

**sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document** 
gives me FT documentId along with the individual keywords within it

Once I had that, the rest was simple.
Although, I do have to look into the term 'keyword' a bit more... seems that definition can be variable.

This only works because the text I am searching for has no white space.
I believe that you could tweak the FTI configuration to work with other scenarios... but I couldn't promise.
I need to look more into Fulltext.

My current 'beta' code below.

```
CREATE TABLE #keyMap 
   (  
      docid INT PRIMARY KEY ,  
      [key] varchar(32) NOT NULL  
   );  
DECLARE @db_id int = db_id(N'<database name>');  
DECLARE @table_id int = OBJECT_ID(N'Transactions'); 

INSERT INTO #keyMap
 EXEC sp_fulltext_keymappings @table_id; 

select  km.[key] as transaction_id, i.[id] as item_id
from    
    sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document ( @db_id, @table_id ) kbd  
    INNER JOIN 
    #keyMap km  ON km.[docid]=kbd.document_id
    inner join [items] i
    on kdb.[display_term] = i.name
   ;
```

My actual version of the code includes inserting the data into a final table.
Execution time is coming in at 30 seconds, which serves my needs for now.